# Docker :: assign different IP address to each container on Synology NAS

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network, synology

I'm getting familiar with Docker thanks to my NAS Syonlogy 1515+.

I have created a **SQL Server 2019** container called `sqlserver4` that listen on port `1433`:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=My_Password" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver4 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

And I have then created a second one called `sqlserver5` that listen on port `1533`:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=My_Password" -p 1533:1533 --name sqlserver5 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

All good, my two servers are there at the IP Address **192.168.1.44**

[image]

I can connect through SSMS to the first one, the `sqlserver4`:

[image]

But when I try to connect to the second one, the `sqlserver5` I receive the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer
> available.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 64)

[image]

It's easy to see where the problem is: even if they are on different port, `1433` and `1533` the IP Address is always the same `192.168.1.44`

How can I setup a different IP Address for each container?

**EDIT:**

@David Maze suggested me to stop `sqlserver4` and try to connect to `sqlserver5`. My assumption was wrong, I cannot connect to `sqlserver5` neither. But fun fact, the error changes:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)

[image]

Comment: Using different ports on the same externally-visible IP address shouldn't be a problem, that's a very normal TCP setup.  If you stop one of the containers, does the other work better?

Comment: My assumption was wrong @DavidMaze, even stopping `sqlserver4` doesn't makes SSMS connect to `sqlserver5` but the error changes. This is interesting. Thank you